# Basic question about limit points.

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $E=(0,1)$, what is the set of limit points for this set? I read somewhere that the set of limit points consist of only 2 elements: 0 and 1. I can understand that these are two limit points because for any real r>0, we can have $d(0,q)<r$ for some $0<q<1$. (Because the real number system is dense.)

What I don't understand is why 0.1, or 0.2, or any other number between 0 and 1 cannot be a limit point? Surely for any real r>0, we can have $d(0.1,q)<r$ for some $0<q<1$?

Comment: I read that in the Rudin's solution manual by Sam Blinstein. You can go google and search "rudin solution Sam Blinstein" and it will be the first result. The exact paragraph is the last paragraph of exercise 6, from page 11. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, $[0,1]$ is the set of limit points of $E$. I don't know where you read that, perhaps they were using a different definition? Perhaps provide a link?

Hmmm, strange. I had a look at it, just above in question 5 he seems to be using limit point in the sense that would imply that $[0,1]$ is indeed the set of limit points of $E$... Perhaps attributable to a slip on the author's behalf? In any case, the rest of the stuff he says about $E'$ is true.

Comment: See comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the limit points of $(0,1)$ in the standard topology is the set $[0,1]$.  Perhaps they meant to say that the boundary of $(0,1)$ is $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: I don't think that was what the author meant, judging from what he said after that.

Answer (score 1):

All points in the closed interval [0,1] are the limit points of (0,1)